# YouTube with react native is not working

Tags: react-native

I take a reference with official website https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube and use command `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube`

When i launch my ios emulator , i get empty view , Why?
[image]

Here is my package version:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^19.0.0",
    "firebase": "^4.2.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-19.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.41.0",
    "react-native-youtube": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
```

I use the code just like official:

```
        <YouTube
            videoId='KVZ-P-ZI6W4'
            play={true}             // control playback of video with true/false
            fullscreen={true}       // control whether the video should play in fullscreen or inline
            loop={true}             // control whether the video should loop when ended
            onReady={e => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
            onChangeState={e => this.setState({ status: e.state })}
            onChangeQuality={e => this.setState({ quality: e.quality })}
            onError={e => this.setState({ error: e.error })}
            style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 300 }}
        />
```

Some one can tell me what step may be i miss it ?

Thanks in advance.

I find this file https://github.com/irccloud/ios/blob/master/YTPlayerView/Assets/YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html
and creat it under my assets folder , what step should i do next ?  i complie still get blank view.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you done the native installation - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube#installation

Comment: Yes , i console.log onError , i can the error show `Warning: Native component for "RCTYouTube" does not exist` , hmm...what is the meaning ?

Comment: @Dan i just `npm install react-native-youtube -S` is ant thing else i should install ?

Comment: You need to import the library e.g. `import YouTube './youtube'`

Comment: @fungusanthrax thanks for your reply , i have import YouTube from 'react-native-youtube';

Comment: you should add `./` if the package/library is in the same folder as your class, otherwise it might be finding the package that is the issue.

Comment: The package is under my dependencies , if you mean YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html its under my assets folder.

Comment: @徐博俊 Are you using exponent? Do you have android / ios folders in your top level folder

Comment: @Eden Yes, i use "expo": "^19.0.0" and according to your reply , i look for another answer , hmm...it looks like expo doesn't support youtbe player for now.

Comment: Not natively. Expo can support it if you detach your application. Google detaching expo.

Comment: I still looking for some answer, the people that using expo suggest use webview.

Answer (score 0):

1. Eject app from the expo.
2. increase the version of react-native. (more than 60.)
3. then link manually in Ios with manual linking.
4. in Android Auto linked. [ref](https://github.com/davidohayon669/react-native-youtube/issues/406#issuecomment-542753680) [enter link description here](https://github.com/davidohayon669/react-native-youtube/issues/389)

Comment: I agreed biplov. Upgrade above 60 is only the solution.
thanks.